# OpenCV SVM::predict() results set always gives same last value

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

Create `Mat` for output of predict function

```
    Mat results = Mat::zeros(200,1,CV_32FC1);
```

Give predict function the features set and the results `Mat` I want the class labels returned in.

```
    svm.predict(features,results);
```

Then the last (or 200th in this case) class label in the results mat will ALWAYS give the same weird number.

```
    qDebug() << k<<":" << results.at<float>(200)
```

200 : 1.4013e-45

`svm` was trained with classes 1 and -1. The rest of the class labels are returned correctly all of them accurate also. No matter the size of the results set or training set I get this weird last class label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0-based indexing.  The last value in an array of 200 elements is the 199th element.  With `at<float>(200)` you are reading junk memory past the end of the array.